# Keras fit_generator using a lot of memory even with small batch sizes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Previously I manually trained my model using model.fit() inside a for loop to train it on small batches of data, due to memory constraints. The problem with this is that I can't have access to all previous histories through history.history, because it's like each time a new model is trained, and previous histories aren't stored anywhere.

When I use model.fit() on a 500 batch size, around 7 GB of my ram gets full. I use keras with tensorflow-cpu back end.
But when I use a generator, even with a batch size of 50 won't fit in memory, and gets swapped onto the disk.

I'm performing classification, using 224*224 images, and I am trying to fine tune vgg face. I'm using vgg face implemented according to this link:
[VGG-Face](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface)

I'm using ResNet and SeNet architectures, as described in the link.

I've previously shuffled my data. I've put aside %20 of my data for test.
My data, image addresses and labels, are stored in a list. The %20 of my training data will be used for validation. For example if batch size is equal to 50, train_data_generator will create a batch with size 40 from the first %80 portion of training data, and vl_data_generator will create a batch with size 10 from the last %20 portion of training data. I've written a class, and by creating an instance and invoking train method
through it, I perform training. Here are generator and training parts of my code, excluding model definitions:

```python
def prepare_input_data(self, batch_addresses):
    image = []
    for j in range(len(batch_addresses)):
        img = cv2.imread(batch_addresses[j])
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        img = img - np.array([103.939, 116.779, 123.68])

        image.append(img)

    data = np.array(image)
    data = data.astype('float32')
    data /= 255

    return data


def train_data_generator(self, addresses, labels, batch_size):
    """Train data generator"""
    #Use first %80 of data for training.
    addresses = addresses[: int(0.8 * len(addresses))]
    labels = labels[: int(0.8 * len(labels))]
    total_data = len(addresses)
    while 1:
        for i in range(total_data / batch_size):
            batch_addresses = addresses[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_labels = labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]

            data = self.prepare_input_data(batch_addresses)

            batch_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(batch_labels, self.nb_class)

            yield data, batch_labels

def val_data_generator(self, addresses, labels, batch_size):
    """Validation data generator"""
    #Use the last %20 of data for validation
    addresses = addresses[int(0.8 * len(addresses)):]
    labels = labels[int(0.8 * len(labels)):]
    total_data = len(addresses)
    image = []
    while 1:
        for i in range(total_data / batch_size):
            batch_addresses = addresses[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_labels = labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]

            data = self.prepare_input_data(batch_addresses)

            batch_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(batch_labels, self.nb_class)

            yield data, batch_labels

def train(self, label_interested_in):
    """Trains the model"""
    #Read training data from json file, and get addresses and labels
    addresses, labels = self.create_address_and_label(label_interested_in)
    batch_size = 50
    train_batch_size = 40
    val_batch_size = 10
    steps = int(len(addresses) / batch_size) + 1
    print(len(addresses), steps)
    #Perform training
    history = self.custom_vgg_model.fit_generator(
        self.train_data_generator(addresses, labels, train_batch_size),
        steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=self.number_of_epochs,
        verbose=1, validation_data=self.val_data_generator(addresses, labels, val_batch_size),
        validation_steps=steps, initial_epoch=0)
```

Why am I seeing such high memory usage? Is it because the way generators work in keras? I read that generators prepare batches beforehand to speedup the training process by running in parallel with the training. Or am I doing something wrong?

As a side question, since there isn't a batch_size argument in fit_generator(), am I correct in assuming that data gets loaded into the model based on generators and gradient updates are performed after each training and validation batch is loaded?

Comment: there is a batch size argument in fit_generator(). Use that to pass your batch size value.

Comment: Also in prepare_input_data() function you are reading an image using cv2 but not closing it. Try that.

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra Thanks for your comment. Sorry I didn't see it in the keras documentation for fit_generator. How does it work with generators? what happens if the batch_size argument is set to 32, the default value, and size of batches obtained from generators is less than that?

Comment: https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: fit() and fit_generators() perform different functions. fit() read data loaded into RAM and fit_generators() read data present in disk. Of course by their given batch size. Nothing really happens if you use your batch size as 32 or 64 or 8 or 16 as long as your system RAM or GPU RAM can really fit it. Its upto you to use any suitable size.

Comment: Regarding the main question, it is natural that a system will incur high memory usage in system RAM or GPU RAM whichever in use. keras generators are actually python generators that loads batches of data or in your case batch size on the fly and release it once done. This is to prevent high memory usage. If you are experiencing system lagging and slowdown then you might need to reduce the batch size or look into the deep learning model architecture.

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra Thanks, you've helped me a lot. I've noticed a bug in my generator, but I don't know how to fix it. 
When I train my network with 800 training data, and 200 validation data, I've noticed that the value of "i" in train generator goes up to 10, with a batch size of 20, which is incorrect. Cause I need 40 batches to finish one epoch. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try `workers=0`

This will not invoke any multiprocessing which is intended to fill up the queue beforehand up to the `max_queue_size` argument with using k workers.
What this does is; prepare a queue of generated data on CPU while training is ongoing on GPU so no time is lost and avoid bottlenecks.

For your need workers=0 will work

For deeper inquiry refer to 
[keras fit_generator](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L153)